# Visibility of buttons in gridview when selecting a row ASP.net c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to make the edit button on the right side of my gridview table visible when selecting a row and  when I select another row the previous row's edit button will disappear. Can you please help me coz I really need it to be done. Thanks!

> 

```
protected void TraineeGrid_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < TraineeGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (TraineeGrid.SelectedIndex == i)
        {

            TraineeGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. Did you try anything? What issue you are facing in that?

Comment: The issue that Im facing is that when I select a single row in the gridview all the edit buttons of the rows get visible. Can you give me some logic on doing that

Comment: Without looking at your code it's impossible to say what's wrong with your code. The logic is to identify the row using current index and show the edit button of that row only

Comment: I already edited my question and attached the code. TraineeGrid.Columns[1] is my edit button

Comment: you are changing the visibility of the whole column upon selecting a row. that is why it is showing all controls at once. you should specifically display the control based on the selected column and row number if you want to.

Comment: yes and I dont know the right syntax to write on my code but I understand how it should be done. I tried TraineeGrid.Rows[i].Columns[1].Visible = true but it doesnt work

Comment: can you teach me the right logic or syntax of doing this please